# Exclusive or with three and more terms

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

How to define in general an n-ary operator $⊕^n$ such that $⊕^n(A_1,…,A_n)$ is true when exactly one of its disjuncts is true, because using binary xor as in $A⊕^2B⊕^2C$, does not have the desired truth conditions.

Comment: "three terms or more does hold iff either hold" -> ???  This is not clear.  "can i use xor for this?" -> for what exactly? Again, not clear. "Using xor three or more times is not equivalent."  -> Is not equivalent to what?  I don't understand your overall question

Comment: I think the OP asks how to define in general an $n$-ary operator $\oplus^n$ such that $\oplus^n(A_1, \ldots, A_n)$ is true when exactly one of its disjuncts is true, because using binary $xor$ as in $A \oplus^2 B \oplus^2 C$, does not have the desired truth conditions. @user23657, is this what you mean?

Comment: @lemontree yes exactly

Comment: How do you interpret the term $A\oplus B \oplus C$, which terms are arguments? In binary notation would you write $\oplus(\oplus (A,B),C)$? And why doesn't it have the desired truth values?

Comment: @GottlobtFrege No matter which bracketing variant one chooses, the formula will come out as true in some situations where more than one disjunct is true: E.g. both $(A \oplus B) \oplus C$  and $A \oplus (B \oplus C)$ are true when $A, B, C$ are all true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just straightforwardly define

> (syntax) If $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are formulas, then $\oplus^n(A_1, \ldots, A_n)$ is a formula.
> (semantics) $[\![\oplus^n(A_1, \ldots, A_n)]\!]^V := 1 \text{ iff for exactly one } i, [\![A_i]\!]^V = 1$.

You can also invent symbol like $\oplus^n$ for it if you want.

If your question is how to define $\oplus$ via other connectives, we have

> $\oplus^n(A_1, \ldots, A_n) \equiv \underbrace{(\underbrace{A_1}_{j=1} \land \neg \underbrace{A_2}_{j=2} \land \ldots \land \neg \underbrace{A_n}_{j=n})}_{i=1} \lor \underbrace{(\neg \underbrace{A_1}_{j=1} \land A_2 \land \neg A_3 \land \ldots )}_{i=2} \lor \ldots \lor \underbrace{(\ldots \land \neg A_{n-1} \land A_n)}_{i=n}$.

i.e. a disjunction of cases where in each disjunct, exactly one formula is true and the others are all false, expressed by a conjunction of negated and unnegated formulas.

If you want a more concise notation, you can write the above using generalized conjunction and disjunction:

> $\oplus^n(A_1, \ldots, A_n) \equiv \bigvee_{i=1}^{n} \bigwedge_{j=1}^{n} \begin{cases} A_j & \text{iff } i = j\\ \neg A_j & \text{iff } i \neq j \end{cases} $

meaning that you have a disjunction of conjunctions in which each formula occurs unnegated if it is that literal which under the current disjunction ($i$) iteration is supposed to be the only true formula, and negated otherwise.

Comment: great, is it also possible to use the binary xor to express the last formula with it? i have in mind that every n-ary operator can be reduced to binary operations.

Comment: To binary operations yes -- that's what I did with negation, conjunction and disjunction. But not necessarily binary xor. As you observed yourself, simply concatenating formulas with binary xor does not yield the desired truth conditions. Perhaps there exists some more complicated construction with binary xor that works (I can't think of one off the top of my head), but I don't see why that would be desirable.

Comment: You could also write the expression using "hat notation" to denote excluding a certain term: $\bigvee_{i=1}^n [(A_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{A_i} \wedge \cdots \wedge A_n) \wedge (\lnot A_i)]$.